# Dynamic DataTables without using Server-side processing

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

So I'm trying to create a simple datatables project without the usage of their Server-side processing. I included the css, js and everything but still can't get it to work. This is what my code looks like:

HTML:

```
<table id="dataTableUsers" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Full Name</th>
              <th>Nickname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Receipt</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for r in results %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{r.first_name}} {{r.last_name}}</td>
              <td>{{r.nickname}}</td>
              <td>{{r.email}}</td>
              <td>{{r.contact}}</td>
              <td>
              <!--<a href="/user/receipt/{{r.accountID}}">View Receipt</a>-->
              <a data-backdrop="true" data-toggle="modal" href="/user/receipt/{{r.accountID}}" data-target="#myModal{{r.accountID}}">View Receipt</a>
              </td>
              <td>

                {% if r.status == 0 %}
                  <a href="/user/{{r.accountID}}/activate">Activate</a>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="/user/{{r.accountID}}/deactivate">Deactivate</a> 
                {% endif %}

              </td>
            </tbody>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
```

And in my php:

```
$app->get('/user/admin/:team', function($team) use($app) {
    $session = new \RKA\Session();
    if($session->logged_in) {
        if($session->type) {
            $db = new db();
            if($team == "all") {
                $results = $db->select("accounts");
            } else {
                $app->redirect('/user/admin/all');
            }
            $app->render('adminpage.html', array(
                'logged_in' => $session->logged_in,
                'type' => $session->type,
                'results' => $results
            ));
        } else {
            $app->redirect('/user/'.$session->logged_in);
        }
    } else {
        $app->flash('msg', 'Please log in first.');
        $app->flash('type', 'danger');      
        $app->redirect('/user/login');
    } 
});
```

Includes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTableUsers').dataTable();
} );
</script>
<link href="/assets/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

BTW, I am using slim framework and twig. I get all the data but can't get the datatables to work. The sorting, search and everything. I think I got the css design but I can't get the main datatables functions to work.

How can I make the datatables work without using their Server-side processing?

Comment: do you have add jquery library?

Comment: @BhavinSolanki Yes sir.

Comment: add class to table **class="table no-more-tables  dataTable"**

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @BhavinSolanki still no luck :(

Comment: what you mean exactly with 'i can't make it working'? is there any error? you get an unwanted behaviour? the issue is the style? do you have any technical info to share with us to solve...which issue?

Comment: Think I know why - you have malformed markup, `</tr>` _after_ `</tbody>`, you need to swap those, i.e `</tr></tbody>`, dataTables can be very sensitive to malformed markup.

Comment: @Paolo I can't get the main function like searching, sorting, show entries by selected number to work..

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad but still the same

Comment: @FewFlyBy the above is all the relevant html code? i can't see the jquery include; is in another code snippet?

Comment: @Paolo The css, jquery, datatables js is in my base template html and the  initialisation is in the html file were the table belongs.

Comment: It works now! The problem is my {% endfor %} position and what @davidkonrad said. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it, this will mark the question closed.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't working because of the positioning of my loop. The new html file now looks like this:

```
<table id="dataTableUsers" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Full Name</th>
              <th>Nickname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Receipt</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for r in results %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{r.first_name}} {{r.last_name}}</td>
              <td>{{r.nickname}}</td>
              <td>{{r.email}}</td>
              <td>{{r.contact}}</td>
              <td>
              <!--<a href="/user/receipt/{{r.accountID}}">View Receipt</a>-->
              <a data-backdrop="true" data-toggle="modal" href="/user/receipt/{{r.accountID}}" data-target="#myModal{{r.accountID}}">View Receipt</a>
              </td>
              <td>

                {% if r.status == 0 %}
                  <a href="/user/{{r.accountID}}/activate">Activate</a>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="/user/{{r.accountID}}/deactivate">Deactivate</a> 
                {% endif %}

              </td>

            </tr>
           {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Before, my `</tbody>` tag is above my `</tr>` which is wrong. And I also moved the `{% enfor %}` below my `</tr>` tag. And now it does work.